# Use CMD to build an Ionic 4 Capacitor app just like Cordova

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I would like to know if there's a way of building an APK file of an ionic 4 capacitor app without going through android studio? With Cordova I use `ionic cordova build android` is there a way of doing the same thing with capacitor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been talk that this would be improved in the future but for the moment its not as seamless as the cordova experience.

You can prep the build using:

```
ionic capacitor copy android
```

But you still need to run it from Android Studio.

Docs for this are here:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android#running-with-capacitor